# Google Photos API Exceeding Quota

Tags: billing, google-photos-api

At the moment I see that the quota for Google Photos API is limited to 10 000/day. What happens if I exceed this value? Is there any billing that will be associated to my account or will I just be restricted until the the next day (when the quota will refresh)?
I have a script that will upload photos stored locally while keeping the folder structure (by creating albums in Google Photos) and I want to find out if there is any potential billing before running it.

Sorry if it is not the right place to ask such a question.